# Will row_number() always break ties in the same way?

Tags: sql, oracle

Will the function `row_number()` always sort the same data in the same way?

Comment: `row_number()` does not sort anything by itself. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm There's an order by clause to specify

Comment: row_number only Generates Serial number of your result set

Comment: That is exactly what I want--I just wondered if the same rows would get the same serial number in different calls.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.  Ordering in SQL is unstable, meaning that the original sort order is *not* preserved.  There is no guarantee that an analytic function or `order by` will return the results in the same order for the same key values.

You can always add a unique id as the last key in the sort to make it reproducible.

EDIT:

Note:  the non-reproduciblity of `order by` is part of the SQL standard.  Oracle documentation does not specify otherwise.  And, in general, I ordering is usually not stable in databases (for equivalent key values).  I would expect `row_number()` to behave the same way.

If you need things in a particular order, you can add `rowid` to the `order by` clause (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/pseudocolumns008.htm#SQLRF00254)).  In fact, `rowid` may solve your problem without `row_number()`.

Comment: I don't understand the order by part you're talking about. Or maybe you're talking about tie results only?

Comment: Okay thanks.  I am working with data lacking a unique key and was wondering if I could use `row_number()` as an additional column to generate one each time I call the table, without having to copy the original data into a new table with the addition of a unique key.

Comment: But if `row_number()` orders the elements differently with each call then obviously that won't work.

Comment: FYI, `rowid` may not be stable over time if row movement is enabled.